# Property 'isLoggedIn' does not exist on type 'AuthService'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular8, angularfire2

This is my code and I'm having this error :

**Property 'isLoggedIn' does not exist on type 'AuthService'**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from "../../auth.service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SecureInnerPagesGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    public router: Router

  ) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if(this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
      window.alert("You are not allowed to access this URL!");
       this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Could you please help me figure out what is the issue here.

Comment: does isloggedin exist in authservice?

Comment: Apparently yes, I found it on a tutorial.